# HPA spawns too many pods

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

This is my hpa configuration.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: customer-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: customer
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 8
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 70
```

The assigned memory and cpu limits for the deployment are like below.

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: 660Mi
    cpu: 100m
  limits:
    memory: 860Mi
    cpu: 500m
```

The number of replicas of the deployment is like below.

```
replicas: 2
```

When I listed the hpa, it is showed like below.

```
NAME                     REFERENCE                           TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
customer-service-hpa     Deployment/customer-service         46%/70%         2         8         4          36d
```

When I deploy the deployment and run

```
kubectl top pods
```

the output is like below.

```
customer-9fddb6649-24r88                   7m           294Mi
customer-9fddb6649-6x97x                   7m           305Mi
customer-9fddb6649-cpg6g                   56m          309Mi
customer-9fddb6649-ldbb2                   12m          314Mi
```

Eventhough the load is low, initially pod count is 4. But the given minimum pod is 2.

Is there any issue in deployment files?

Comment: You may have set the `replicas` value in your deployment to 4.

Comment: No.  it is replicas: 2

Comment: Pls can add the deployment yaml to the question (redact any confidential stuff as needed) so we can see what you are trying to do. Also, if you monitor the pods as the deployment happens (`watch kubectl get pods -n {namespace}`) do the older pods disappear soon after the new pods appear? If so, then it actually sounds like correct deployment rollout behaviour (create new pods, wait for them to come good, then delete older pods)

Comment: With 4 pods you are seeing 46%/70%. Try minReplicas: 1 and maxReplicas: 2 and see if the load goes over 70%. If true, your workload ain't that small as you thought at the point in time when you captured the stats.